# Range of cubic equation

Tags: real-analysis, cubics

I know that the range of $f(x)= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is $\mathbb{R}$ but I can't prove it . It's obvious from the shape but I'm looking for a rigorous proof . I've tried to use IVT but didn't get any result .

Comment: hint:  If $a\neq 0$ then consider the limits as $x\to \pm \infty$.  (if $a=0$ then your claim may not be true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: write $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=x^3\left(a+\frac{b}{x}+\frac{c}{x^2}+\frac{d}{x^3}\right)$$ and compute the Limit for $x$ tends to $$\pm\infty$$
since $$\frac{b}{x},\frac{c}{x^2},\frac{d}{x^3}$$ tends to Zero for $$x$$ tends to$$\pm  \infty$$
we get as a result $$\pm\infty \cdot \sign(a)$$

Comment: i know it is not in the form $\infty\cdot 0$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can we prove it using IVT ?

Comment: i think this is also possible but since every polynomial is continuous this is enough

Comment: I think it is incomplete because we can use the same argument for the quadratic equation and then it leads us to a wrong answer . We need more information .

Comment: sorry but i don't know how is the $\sign$ symbol

Comment: How can you use the same argument for a quadratic? $x^2$ doesn't go to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$

Comment: yes you can use the same Argument it is $$x^2\left(a+\frac{b}{x}+\frac{c}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Oh , I see . Can we conclude that the range of odd power is $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Exactly. Odd degree polynomials have end behavior just like odd power functions, hence they have full range.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs So what about even degrees ? Is there any general rule ?

Comment: Sure. If the lead coefficient is positive, then the range is $[a,\infty)$ for some real $a$, and it's $(-\infty,a]$ if the lead coefficient is negative.

Comment: I think it's wrong . For example consider $x^2 - 2x + 1$

Comment: it is $$x^2\left(1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)->+\infty$$ as$x$ tends to $\pm \infty$

Comment: Okay but we need global minimum for determining range .

Comment: The range of $x^2-2x+1$ is $[a,\infty)$ for some real $a$, namely for $a=0$.

Comment: Okay and that's the global minimum . I thought your mean by $a$ is the leading coefficient . Sorry for misunderstanding .